# Three.js set texture to inline svg

Tags: three.js, textures

I am not sue of this is even possible but instead of setting a texture to a jpg like THREE.TextureLoader().load('./texture1.jpg')

I want to set the texture to an INLINE SVG (I want to animate with javascript GSAP).

Is this possible?  Probably not :(

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, it's not. You can't use a SVG file as a texture. However, you can load SVG files in `three.js` via [THREE.SVGLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=svgl#examples/en/loaders/SVGLoader) and then create shape meshes from the resulting path data.

But keep in mind this is a one-time operation. If you animate the SVG, you won't see any effect after the loading process.